# Secure (HTTPS) connection requires port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, serve

When I list my web app trough https it requires port (Even if its 80).
If I start it with http, it works fine without need of the default port.

To start I am using `serve -s build -l 80 --cert....`

So for example:

**Wont work**

```
https://example.com/
```

**Will work**

```
https://example.com:80/
```

if I host my web app without https (SSL Secure connection) it will host successfully and works without port as well.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're listening on port 80 then https://example.com/ wont work since https default port is 443.

Try http://example.com/ instead or use port 443 with ssl

Comment: Oh, its probably first time working with SSL tpye of things and https, didint know it has different https port. Thanks alot.